# UWP: Highlight ListBoxItem - Events That Coincide with the Highlighting

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have a ListBox bound to a collection of items of type Definition. My requirement is that every time the mouse is hovered over the area of a templated ListBoxItem, a second ListBox open next to the ListBoxItem, revealing sub-items which are of type Word.

(I am basically implementing something similar to a TreeView using two ListBoxes. This is for earlier versions so using a TreeView control is not an option.)

This is the data structure...

```
public class Word
{
    public string Name { get; set; }                
}

public class Definition 
{
    public string Name { get; set }
    public ObservableCollection<Word> Words;
}

public class Dictionary
{
    public string Name { get; set }
    public ObservableCollection<Definition> Definitions;
}
```

And here is the XAML view...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    <Button Grid.Row="0"
        Height="0">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout x:Name="DefinitionFlyout"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="WordsListBox"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemp late x:DataType="local:Word">
                            <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                Height="Auto" 
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Text="{x:Bind Name}"
                                TextAlignment="Left"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>              
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
    <ListBox x:Name="DefinitionsListBox" 
        Grid.Row="1"                                                     
                SelectionMode="Single"                                                      
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>                                                        
                                </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Definition">                                                        
                            <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap"                                                                     
                                    Height="Auto"                                                                  
                                        BorderThickness="0"                                                                      
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                                                                 
                                        Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TwoWay}">                                                                
                                </TextBox>                                                        
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

When the mouse pointer hovers over a Definition item in DefinitionsListBox, WordsListBox should fly out and display the Words of that Definition. And when the pointer exits that Definition and hovers over a new one, I want WordsListBox to reflect that change.

Unfortunately, I can't find the events that will help me accomplish this.

I thought defining PointerEntered and PointerExited in the TextBox of Definition would do the trick but they don't because PointerExited fires IMMEDIATELY after PointerEntered, as in almost simultaneously, and not when the mouse exits the TextBox area. And SelectionChanged of ListBox doesn't fire.

The first event should fire when ListBoxItem highlighting begins, and the second one, when the highlighting ends.

What do you recommend for this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought defining PointerEntered and PointerExited in the TextBox of Definition would do the trick but they don't because PointerExited fires IMMEDIATELY after PointerEntered, as in almost simultaneously.

The problem is the when `Flyout` show at the button there is a mask layer cover on the window. This will prevent basic input event of `TextBox` defined. It looks `PointerExited` fires immediately after `PointerEntered`  as in almost simultaneously.

For solving this , you could set `OverlayInputPassThroughElement` property for Flyout that make the area of `ListBox` could response `PointerEntered` `PointerExited` event when Flyout is opened. For more please refer the following code.

```
 <Flyout x:Name="DefinitionFlyout" OverlayInputPassThroughElement="{x:Bind DefinitionsListBox}">
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much for making me aware of this property!!

Comment: Pleasure is all mine.